# rails; shoulda-matchers suddenly give uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

As you see between the first and second savings in the spec file ~15s passed. After the first saving I got the error because of the typo, then suddenly after the second saving I started getting the `uninitialized constant: Shoulda (NameError)`.

Since then I've been getting this error after every save. Before this issue everything worked fine.

Why is this happening?

```
16:15:03 - INFO - Running: spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 91917
/Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load': /Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
    let(:executed_task { create(:task, executor: user) }
                        ^
/Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:106:in `setup'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
16:15:04 - ERROR - Failed: "spring rspec -f progress -r /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/guard-rspec-4.6.4/lib/guard/rspec_formatter.rb -f Guard::RSpecFormatter --failure-exit-code 2  spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb" (exit code: 1)

16:15:17 - INFO - Running: spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 91930
/Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/spec/rails_helper.rb:16:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Shoulda (NameError)
    from /Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:106:in `setup'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
16:15:20 - ERROR - Failed: "spring rspec -f progress -r /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/guard-rspec-4.6.4/lib/guard/rspec_formatter.rb -f Guard::RSpecFormatter --failure-exit-code 2  spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb" (exit code: 1)

16:15:43 - INFO - Running: spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 91941
/Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/spec/rails_helper.rb:16:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Shoulda (NameError)
    from /Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:106:in `setup'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
16:15:45 - ERROR - Failed: "spring rspec -f progress -r /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/guard-rspec-4.6.4/lib/guard/rspec_formatter.rb -f Guard::RSpecFormatter --failure-exit-code 2  spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb" (exit code: 1)

16:16:39 - INFO - Running: spec/models/conversation_spec.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 91963
/Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/spec/rails_helper.rb:16:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Shoulda (NameError)
    from /Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/spec/models/conversation_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:106:in `setup'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Silo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
16:16:41 - ERROR - Failed: "spring rspec -f progress -r /Users/Silo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/guard-rspec-4.6.4/lib/guard/rspec_formatter.rb -f Guard::RSpecFormatter --failure-exit-code 2  spec/models/conversation_spec.rb" (exit code: 1)
```

Comment: Well, what if you fix the syntax error? It should be `let(:executed_task) { create(:task, executor: user) }`.  How're you including shoulda-matchers?

Comment: I've commented out that file, also tried to delete the whole `spec/controllers` dir. Exactly as it is written in the docs. I've put it in the`rails_helper`. The funny stuff is that it worked till now.

Comment: j-dexx, as I'm looking at the log I realized if there is a syntax error then I get that error, if not then I get the uninitialized constant. So the 2 things not related at all. On the other hand I've made a `git commit` since it worked last time properly. Can committing or changing branch cause any issue?

Comment: j-dexx, I found this on the github page of shoulda: `NOTE: Shoulda Matchers is currently undergoing a changing of the guard. We will not be as responsive to answer questions or issues while we make this transition. Sorry about that.` Do you think it is related?

Comment: I've reinstalled the `shoulda-matchers` gem and it's working now, but it doesn't make any sense.